# PostgreSQL constraint to prevent overlapping ranges

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wonder if it's possible to write a constraint that would make ranges unique. These ranges are represented as two string-typed columns bottom and top. Say, If I have the following row in a database,

```
| id | bottom |  top  |
|----|--------|-------|
| 1  | 10000  | 10999 |
```

inserting the row (2, 10100, 10200) would immediately result in constraint violation error. 
**P.S**
I can't switch to integers, unfortunately -- only strings

Comment: See here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never store numbers as strings, and always use a [range data](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) type like `int4range` to store ranges. With ranges, you can easily use an exclusion constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE tab ADD EXCLUDE USING gist (bottom_top WITH &&);
```

Here, `bottom_top` is a range data type.

If you have to stick with the broken data model using two string columns, you can strip `#` characters and still have an exclusion constraint with

```
ALTER TABLE tab ADD EXCLUDE USING gist (
   int4range(
      CAST(trim(bottom, '#') AS integer),
      CAST(trim(top,    '#') AS integer),
      '[]'
   ) WITH &&
);
```